# How to use custom fonts in emgucv?

Tags: c#, emgucv

I know how to draw text on image in Emgu CV:

```
CvFont f = new MCvFont(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.FONT.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, 1);
image.Draw("something", ref f, new Point(0, 0), new Rgb(0, 0, 0));
```

but I don't know how to use other fonts instead of CV_FONT_HARSHEY*

**UPDATE:**

This is complete solution:

```
var b = image.Bitmap;
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);
Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", 16);
SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
PointF drawPoint = new PointF(0,0);
g.DrawString("something,", drawFont, drawBrush, drawPoint);

/// after drawing etc.

image.Bitmap = b;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add TTF file in `PrivateFontCollection`

```
// 'PrivateFontCollection' is in the 'System.Drawing.Text' namespace
var foo = new PrivateFontCollection();
// Provide the path to the font on the filesystem
foo.AddFontFile("...");

var myCustomFont = new Font((FontFamily)foo.Families[0], 36f);
```

And then you draw image like this:

```
image.Draw("something", myCustomFont, new Point(0, 0), new Rgb(0, 0, 0));
```

Or you can use method from myCustomFont: `Graphics.DrawString`

Comment: I have error: 
Error 5 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Font' to 'ref Emgu.CV.Structure.MCvFont'

Comment: Hmm. You can try with Graphics.DrawString and will work. I try find how convert Font MCvFont

Comment: I created:  `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image.Bitmap);`  But it is not working. Do you have better idea how to use bitmap ?

Comment: You don't need create image. You just show text. TTF have own pixel texture. Use `Graphics.DrawString`

Answer (score 0):

// this solution draws test over a Mat image

```
{   
    var b = myMat.ToBitmap();  
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);
    Font drawMFont = new Font("Calibri", 8, FontStyle.Bold);
    SolidBrush drawMBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.DarkCyan); 
    PointF drawMPoint = new PointF(1, 4);
    g.DrawString("Hello",drawMFont,drawMBrush, drawMPoint);
}
```